# What is a transient attack?

Tags: attacks, attack-prevention

I just faced a problem of an IP is taking forever to respond, i had been told it might be a transient attack.... I tried googling it, but cant really find more info.

Can anyone kindly explain to me what is a transient attack? And if there are anyway for me to isolate which exact part is getting attacked(If it is between my router to the ISP, ISP, or ISP to the server)

Thanks!

Comment: Who told you? Can you ask them?

Comment: A volunteer that also used the same service on the forum. I did a traceroute and follow it all the way to the Amazon server in Seattle and that server tooks forever to respond, it does respond but takes forever, and sometimes it doesnt. And when i ask a friend to try it from a different region, that problem does not occur. The guy that told me that and helped me just said it is probably a transient attack between my ISP and the server.... and that was it. And i couldnt find info on what that is.

Comment: Maybe it is a ddos... i am not sure, its just that a uploading process has became very slow... and sometime it is even timed out.

Comment: This simply means that this is only temporary, i.e. not a permanent hack but only a short DOS. http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/transient: ..lasting only a short time; existing briefly; temporary.

Comment: ooo.... thanks... yer i was a little confused.... its been going for nearly 1 week....

Comment: I think the thing to do is to forget what this mysterious volunteer said and work the problem. Start with your ISP and move on from there.

Comment: Hi yer, worked backward, traced the route, found the exact IP address and the server that was having problem, but that wasnt my server or i didnt have any access to that......then when i woke up, everything was back to normal...

Answer (score 0):

A "transient attack" is simply an attack that is not permanent.

However, you aren't actually sure whether this is an attack or another issue e.g. a routing problem between your ISP and the target host.

As you are experiencing problems since one week, you should contact your ISP, telling them that the target host seems to work fine.

Comment: Hi Thanks! Yer there were a few other people also had this problem, and they were from totally different region. So i traced route and there was a specific IP that was responding very slow, some Amazon server.... and the service that was using was on the AWS....... and i didnt have access or anything to that....and i waited for a day, and it went back to normal..